# How can I move the percent sign after the number when I output?

Tags: java

*Code*

```
System.out.println("Name            Grade       Letter Grade    Grade (- Lowest)        Difference");
System.out.println("---------------------   --------------  --------------  ----------------------  ----------");
System.out.printf("%-23s %-15.1f %%%-15s %-23.1f %%%.1f\n", name, grade, letterGrade, lowGrade, diff);
```

*Output*

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj5Yu.jpg)

I want the percent sign in right place

Comment: By using %.1f%% ?

Comment: @Marged Absurd as it sounds, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Please read the answer, and accept one if it answers your question, this is a how SO work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In a formatted string the `%` is a special character, so to print a percent symbol, it has to be escaped*

As `%%%.1f\n` prints the percent symbol and then the formatted number, the solution is to reverse this pattern : number and then symbol : `%.1f%%`

Answer (score 2):

Put the escaped percent sign at the right place, for example:

```
%.1f%%
```